# SQL - Server - What is sp_addextendedproperty commonly used for, and is it likely this code (see) is auto generated?

Tags: sql-server

Just after a quick answer here. I've come across this view in a database I'm working on. It has a large code section beneath it which uses sp_addextendedproperties.

This code looks like it was generated by a tool to me (preview below) - can any one tell me which tool it likely came from and what the point of it is (Just some of the text is pasted below)?

I would say I have a reasonable amount of experience with SQL server, but not really come across this before.

```
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_DiagramPane1', @value=N'[0E232FF0-B466-11cf-A24F-00AA00A3EFFF, 1.00]
Begin DesignProperties = 
   Begin PaneConfigurations = 
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 0
         NumPanes = 4
         Configuration = "(H (1[16] 4[10] 2[51] 3) )"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 1
         NumPanes = 3
         Configuration = "(H (1 [50] 4 [25] 3))"
      End
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The property value is created by the View designer in MS SQL Server Management Studio, and describes the layout of the graphical view definition.

Edit:

The name of the view is given by the parameters you omitted in the code:

```
, @level0type=N'SCHEMA', @level0name=N'dbo'
, @level1type=N'VIEW', @level1name=N'MyView'
```